# Why pow method working not properly in dart?

Tags: dart, math

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
print(raiseTopower());
}

raiseTopower() {
  stdout.write('Enter first number ');
  int x = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  stdout.write('Enter second number ');
  int y = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  double result = pow(x, y);
  print('Result is $result');
}
```

pow() method not working properly. please guide me.
overall code is correct but pow() occur error where syntactically is right.
Thanks!

Comment: pow returns a num, not a double

Comment: please provide more information about your problem. What error do you get? What do you expect the code to do? What did you try to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tomtom also says, the [`pow`](https://%20https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.5/dart-math/pow.html) method is defined to return the `num` type which means it can be both `int` and `double`:

> Returns `x` to the power of `exponent`.
>
> If `x` is an int and `exponent` is a non-negative int, the result is an int, otherwise both arguments are converted to doubles first, and the result is a double.
>
> For integers, the power is always equal to the mathematical result of `x` to the power `exponent`, only limited by the available memory.

If you want the result to be a `double` regardless, the safest would be to call [`toDouble()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.5/dart-core/num/toDouble.html) on the result:

> This number as a double.
>
> If an integer number is not precisely representable as a double, an approximation is returned.

So something like:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  raiseToPower();
}

void raiseToPower() {
  stdout.write('Enter first number ');
  int x = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  
  stdout.write('Enter second number ');
  int y = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  
  double result = pow(x, y).toDouble();
  print('Result is $result');
}
```

I also fixed another problem in your code where you tried to print the output of your `raiseToPower()` method, but the method does not return anything. In general, you should always specify the return type of your functions and if you don't expect a method to return anything, then use `void` as the type.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost nothing wrong with your code, but the missing `void` before your function `raiseTopower()`. Also, as someone said in comments section, pow() returns a num. So you need to add .toDouble() in order to get the results you want. Try this:

```
void raiseTopower() {


 stdout.write('Enter first number ');
  int x = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  stdout.write('Enter second number ');
  int y = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  double result = pow(x, y).toDouble();
  print('Result is $result');
}
```

Comment: You are wrong about the issue and this is therefore also not the way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Julemand. I didn't notice that.